# xcode: Problems connecting main storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am following the tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH3-SW1). I just created my first storyboard and tried to set it as the main storyboard. After following the tutorial I clicked the run button and the simulator doesn't render any of the changes ive created.

I have a screen shot of my xcode project here(not sure how else to display it): https://app.box.com/s/okw7jlzq5zmcetd5cehu

What am I doing wrong?

Here is another screenshot of the storyboard itself: https://app.box.com/s/jt6i0an3maowwvgsamk7

Answer (score 0):

Place a checkmark in the box "Is Initial View Controller" for the view controller you want to load.

[image]

Comment: Ok, There are a couple of reason this could be happening. In the main.m file, does your line say UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"XYZAppDelegate");

Comment: It says: @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([XYZAppDelegate class]));
    }

Comment: That's fine. Can you post the AppDelegate.m file?

Comment: Look in the info.plist file and see if the storyboard name is Main with a capital M or a lowercase m.

Comment: This is what I have going on in there: https://app.box.com/s/6mytm86jvwuqurh446ka

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50734/discussion-between-pcoder123-and-apathybear)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the code in the app delegate. When you use a storyboard, you don't need anything in there except "return YES". The storyboard creates the window, so the code you have in there is making another window, not the one that your storyboard controller is a subview of.

Using this tutorial might teach you some things about the structure of an iOS app, but if you just want to make an app with a storyboard, you should start with the "single view" template instead of the "empty" one. It will give you a storyboard and an initial controller.